# Can normal map use separate uv set?

Tags: three.js

My problem is that after exporting a 3d model from Blender to json
with 3 uv sets and 3 different textures(diffuse map, normal map and light map) it looks like normal map is using the same uv set as diffuse map. 
I've been wondering if it's possible that normalMap in THREE.MeshPhongMaterial can use separate UV set, just like LightMap? Or it only uses the same uv set as DiffuseMap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `THREE.MeshPhongMaterial`, all the maps share the primary UV set, with the exception of the `lightMap` and the `aoMap`, which share the 2nd set of UVs.

If you want different behavior, you will have to create a custom `ShaderMaterial`.

three.js r.71

Comment: thank you, this really helped me, but i have another question associated with uv mapping. I have a json model this time with 2 uv sets and two textures ( normalMap and lightmap). Unfortunatelly after importing it I noticed that the lightMap is mapped incorrectly and probably using the first uv set. But when i modify a json file and change "mapNormal" property to "mapBump" everything is mapped correctly. What can cause this problem?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. If you have a new issue, please make a new post. Provide sufficient information so the issue can be replicated.